WCF client works with .NET Framework but not with .NET Core:
I have a WSDL file that I tried to import into .NET Framework and .NET Core code.
In .NET Framework, it works fine, but in .NET Core, it throws the following error:
"The SSL connection could not be established. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."
I have tried all possible solutions, including:
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault;
// and specifying other protocols like Tls, Tls1.2, etc.

However, I keep getting the same error.
ere is the .NET Core code:
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault;
ApiPortTypeClient api = new ApiPortTypeClient();
api.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = this.m_Certificate;
api.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(this.Url);

OOhlsapi gto;
string fehlercode;
string fehlertext;

string resp = api.get(usr, new string[] { "description" }, out gto, out fehlercode, out fehlertext);

and Here is the .Net Framwork Code:
OOApi api=new OOApi();

api.ClientCertificates.Add(this.m_Certificate);
api.Url=m_Url;

OOhlsapi gto;
string fehlercode;
string fehlertext;
string resp= api.get(usr, new string[] {"description"}, out gto, out fehlercode, out fehlertext);

Any suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

At the moment I'm speculating that the cause might be an issue with the certificate. Your certificate is not self-signed. There is a security mechanism in ASP.NET Core, and you should turn the certificate into a trusted certificate.

@QI You Certificate is trusted(chain.Build(certificate); return true) but not self-signed.
is there is any soltion for this issue?

Do you use TLS 1.2 or later?

i am using TLS 1.2

At the moment, I have two thoughts:1.You can generate a log to see where the problem came from. 2.Use code System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

Are you referencing WSDL documents directly to the client as a service? If so, try using svcutil.exe to convert WSDL documents into WCF service code. Use the command svcutil to generate a cs code file. Then edit the app.config file yourself. Add run logs to view the source of the problem.
